# Insert random data in Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I wan to create random data in Oracle table:

```
CREATE TABLE EVENTS(
  EVENTID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  SOURCE VARCHAR2(50 ),
  TYPE VARCHAR2(50 ),
  EVENT_DATE DATE,
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(100 )
)
/
```

I tried this:

```
BEGIN  
FOR loop_counter IN 1..1000 
LOOP 
INSERT INTO EVENTS (EVENTID, SOURCE, TYPE, EVENT_DATE, DESCRIPTION) VALUES (loop_counter, loop_counter, 'warning', 
DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE '2000-01-01','J') ,TO_CHAR(DATE '9999-12-31','J')), dbms_random.value(1,100)); 
END LOOP; 
COMMIT; 
END;
```

I get this error exception

> Error report - ORA-06550: line 5, column 13: PL/SQL: ORA-00932:
>   inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER ORA-06550: line 4,
>   column 1: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Can you give me advice how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Yes, I updated the post.

Comment: That `dbms_random()` call will also not return a date, so it will fail if you try to insert a number like `3684482.0997` into a `DATE` column

Comment: How I have to update it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use:

```
BEGIN  
FOR loop_counter IN 1..1000 LOOP 
INSERT INTO "EVENTS" (EVENTID, "SOURCE", TYPE, EVENT_DATE, DESCRIPTION) 
VALUES (loop_counter, loop_counter, 'warning', 
        TO_DATE(TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE '2000-01-01','J') ,TO_CHAR(DATE '9999-12-31','J'))),'J')
        ,dbms_random.value(1,100)
       ); 
END LOOP; 
COMMIT; 
END;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e1704c/12/1)**</kbd>

Changes:

1. Add mising `;` after final `END`
2. Quote keywords
3. Rewrite random date generation

Answer (score 3):

Also, if you use PL/SQL Developer by Allroundautomations, you can find out
good tool for this job: Data Generator.
It can be very useful, because it can help to generate some data 
in any types and place it to a tables.

(see screenshot attached) [image]

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO EVENTS (EVENTID, "SOURCE", TYPE, EVENT_DATE, DESCRIPTION)
SELECT level, level, 'warning', 
        TO_DATE(TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE '2000-01-01','J') ,TO_CHAR(DATE '9999-12-31','J'))),'J')
        ,dbms_random.value(1,100)
  FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000;
```